# Sample Script Submission

Tags: script, scriptwriting, videogame, jobs

A job opening for a video game appeared and I was asked to submit a sample script. Ideally a video game one, but film also works.
What should I submit? A random passage from a script I wrote, a short story formatted as a script, the first pages of a script?
What's the standard for sample script submissions?

Comment: Is this a script for an existing project or franchise, or is it an opportunity to develop something completely new?

Comment: @ChrisSunami They did not say it exactly, but I believe the role is as part of an existing franchise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, the advice for sample scripts is to write a sample for a close competitor of your target.  It may sound counter-intuitive, but it shows that you can write in the immediate ballpark of what they are looking for, but without raising issues with

a) your conception of the characters not aligning with theirs and
  b) the possibility that you might sue them if they reject your script and then use a similar idea.

In general, you want your sample to be as close as possible to what you'd actually be working on, but without stepping on anyone's toes.  It makes it much easier for them to evaluate you for the specific role than if you submit something entirely unrelated.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful. If they ask for multiple samples, should I then write in different styles/on different topics?